# SMLNJ list traversion

Tags: sml, smlnj

How would I go about traversing a list in SMLNJ. I have been at this for 3 hours now and I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

So just to traverse and print a list out. In the simplest way [5,2,3] would print out 5 2 3 or a list variant of this.

Comment: Why not show what sort of things you have been doing in those 3 hours? What is your best attempt? That would give us some idea of where the problem lies.

Comment: There should be numerous examples of working with lists in whatever material you're learning from. Paulson's *ML for the Working Programmer* is available for free (and legally) [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/MLbook/pub-details.html). Lists is chapter three.

Comment: Side note: contrary to many other languages, printing isn't something you do a lot in ML, at least not while learning; it isn't even mentioned until the last chapters in Paulson. Instead, you write functions that produce values. Try to create a list where all elements are doubled (i.e. `[5,2,3]` --> `[10,4,6]`) or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I go about traversing a list in SMLNJ

It depends on the type of traversal you want to do: mapping, folding, iterating.

Using recursion:

```
(* mapping: *)
fun incr_each_by_1 [] = []
  | incr_each_by_1 (x::xs) = x + 1 :: incr_each_by_1 xs

val demo_1 = incr_each_by_1 [5,2,3] (* [6,3,4] *)

(* folding: *)
fun sum_all_together [] = 0
  | sum_all_together (x::xs) = x + sum_all_together xs

val demo_2 = sum [5,2,3] (* 10 *)

(* iteration: *)
fun print_each [] = ()
  | print_each (x::xs) = ( print (Int.toString x ^ "\n") ; print_each xs )

val demo_3 = print_each [5,2,3] (* no result, but side-effect *)
```

Using higher-order functions:

```
val demo_1 = List.map (fn x => x + 1) [5,2,3]
val demo_2 = List.foldl (fn (x, result) => x + result) 0 [5,2,3]
val demo_3 = List.app (fn x => Int.toString x ^ "\n") [5,2,3]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!